# my Admin Route is not Working in laravel10

Tags: ubuntu, laravel-10, php-8.1

In my case, I have installed Laravel 10 in UBUNTU, after installation,
I created front and admin routes, but there is a problem with routes,
the front route is working, but the admin route is not working, when I call the admin route it says,

```
Not Found
The requested URL was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.41 (Ubuntu) Server at localhost Port 80
```

---

```
php8.1 artisan --version 
Laravel Framework 10.15.0

php8.1 -v 
PHP 8.1.21 (cli) (built: Jul 8 2023 07:09:57) 
(NTS) Copyright (c) The PHP Group Zend Engine v4.1.21, 
Copyright (c) Zend Technologies with Zend OPcache v8.1.21, 
Copyright (c), by Zend Technologies
```

**Routes**

```
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\front\HomePageController::class,'index'])->name('home.index');

Route::get('/dashboard', [App\Http\Controllers\admin\DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

**Controllers**
**/var/www/html/laravel10/app/Http/Controllers/front/HomePageController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\front;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
class HomePageController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {       
        return view('front.index');
    }
}
?>
```

**/var/www/html/laravel10/app/Http/Controllers/admin/DashboardController.php**

```
<?php
namespace App\Http\Controllers\admin;
use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use DB;
class DashboardController extends Controller
{
    public function index()
    {    
        return view('admin.index');
    }   
}
?>
```

**Views /var/www/html/laravel10/resources/views/front/index.blade.php**

```
<?php
  echo "Front";
?>
```

**/var/www/html/laravel10/resources/views/admin/index.blade.php**

```
<?php
  echo "Admin";
?>
```

everything is perfect front URL is working fine,
**https://localhost/laravel10/public**

but the admin URL is not working
**https://localhost/laravel10/public/dashboard**

when I comment front route and run the admin route(in admin route I remove */dashboard* ) its works like below

```
/* Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\front\HomePageController::class,'index'])->name('home.index'); */
Route::get('/', [App\Http\Controllers\admin\DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');
```

**/var/www/html/laravel10/public/.htaccess**

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Send Requests To Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

I don't understand what is happening here, I also checked in Laravel Log, and there is no error, even I checked in the apache2 log, also there is no error, I also checked the Folder permission, and all permission are correct,

please help me with this

Thanks.

Comment: How did you configure your htaccess? Why does your URL contain `public` at the end?

Comment: @NicoHaase my htaccess file is in the public folder not in the root folder.

Comment: Put a \ before controllers class follow the below code

Route::get('/', [\App\Http\Controllers\front\HomePageController::class,'index'])->name('home.index');

Route::get('/dashboard', [\App\Http\Controllers\admin\DashboardController::class,'index'])->name('dashboard');